# Rewrites for removing index.php stopped working

Tags: .htaccess, index.php, mod-rewrite

After moving from one server to another the .htaccess-rewrites for removing the index.php stopped working.
Old server: PHP 5.3.27 / Apache 2.4.3
New server: PHP 5.6.6 / Apache 2.4.12

There is an index.php in the root-directory and the following .htaccess-directives

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

There is a subfolder called /foo with an index.php and the following .htaccess-directives

```
RewriteEngine On

# -- Removes index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Now on the new server, whatever I do and whatever I change the index.php in the root-folder is executed. Even if I directly call the URL /foo/index.php I end up with index.php being run.

Unfortunately the hoster is not being helpful at all. Any ideas?